# What is the Celebration in the Movie Swades

Tags: swades

In the 2004 Indian Film [Swades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swades), what is the celebration that occurs about halfway through the movie?

Gita performs in it and there is singing but I'm curious what the festival is actually called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens to be cosmic coincidence because am answering this on same day of festival.

Gita and others are performing opera about [Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana) in which [Sita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sita) is held captive by [Ravana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana), while her husband [Rama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) crosses Indian ocean to reach [Sri Lanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanka) to kill Ravana and free Sita.

**[Vijayadashami aka Dasara or Dusshera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijayadashami)**

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of the festival which made me curious if it was the same one I had seen in the movie. (Had a co-worker take Friday off for Durga Puja). Thanks for answering!